# Clicking Link in emacs no longer opens page in browser

Tags: firefox, emacs

Up until yesterday, clicking a link in emacs would open the corresponding page in my browser (Firefox). Sometime yesterday this changed to always open a new window in the browser, on the home page. Any idea what changed - and how to fix it?

GNU Emacs: 24.4.1
Firefox: 36.0
Ubuntu: 14.04

Appears related to reported Ubuntu Firefox bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1425972).

Comment: See also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9636/2064

Comment: Opening the link in EWW works for me.  Then typing `&` inside EWW opens the link in Firefox.  It is interesting that this works and `(setq browse-url-generic-program "firefox")` apparently does not.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: Firefox version 36 has removed the **-remote** option (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Remote_Control)). The emacs-lisp function **browse-url-firefox** uses this option on non-Windows systems. Changing the function to never use remote option solves the problem.

What specifically you can do: **browse-url-firefox** is defined in the emacs-lisp associated with your version of emacs - for me: **/usr/local/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/net/browse-url.el**. You can either edit **browse-url.el**, or redefine the function **browse-url-firefox** elsewhere. The specific change in the function **browse-url-firefox** is to change:

```
(use-remote
      (not (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))))
```

to:

```
(use-remote nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following bits to your ~/.emacs file to fix this issue:

```
;; work around the bogus "-remote" flag specified by browse-url-firefox
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic)
(setq browse-url-generic-program "firefox")
```

The "generic" browser doesn't try to be smart about "-remote"; it just calls whatever program is configured. Incidentally, Firefox does the right thing when called like that anyway, so the whole "-remote" business is pointless anyway.